# file content to JSON encoded String in Java

Tags: java, json, xml, file, encode

I want to read the content of a file, save it to a string and convert this string to a JSON encoded string.

For example I have a XML file with the following content (simplified):

```
<node name="myname">
    <id>123-abc</id>
</node>
```

It's only an example. The file type is not relevant, it can be a XML, a txt file or whatever. The main point is that I want to read a file content and convert this file content to a JSON encodes string.

Now I read this file with `BufferedReader` line for line and convert it to a String.

But this String is not JSON encoded. Now I've tried to convert it to a JSON String with `JSONObject.quote(xmlString)`. I thought that this was the solution, but it isn't so. After doing that the string looks like:

```
"<node name=\"myname\">\t<id>123-abc<\/id><\/node>"
```

After that I've tried replacing all `\t` and the `"` at the beginning and the end of the string with an empty string, but this is not a smart solution. There have to be a standard solution I hope.

So, what can be a simple solution to convert a XML file content to an encoded JSON string?

Comment: Parse XML to POJO, Convert POJO to JSON Object.

Comment: @Compass But I don't want to convert a XML to JSON Object, I only want to encode the file content to a JSON string. So, the file don't have to be a XML file, it can also be a txt file. The main point is that I want to read the content of a file to a string and convert this string to a JSON encoded string.

Comment: So you just want a String in a JSON Object?

Comment: @Compass Not really. I have a REST API endpoint. This endpoint expects a json. One json parameter requires as value a string. this string should contain a json encoded xml string. Later this encoded json xml string will be decoded by the server to a XML. And so I need only a string with XML in it.

Comment: @Martin , Can you throw some light on what is wrong with the output that you got?

Answer (score 0):

With [JAXB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html) you can bind XML documents to POJOs. And then from a Java Object you can use e.g [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)

Try to Google mkyong.com. He has good basic tutorials for both JAXB and Jackson. Can't post more than 2 links as I dont have enough reputation.